# Google AutoML Translation - Cold Start

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-translate, google-cloud-automl, automl

I'm using Google AutoML Translation with custom models. It works fine but there is one issue that bothers me.

If I do not use language pair (e.g. English-Spanish) for a while there is a cold start and the request takes more than **10 seconds**. Whereas the next call is very quick and it takes around **0.5s**.
In my application, I support many language pairs and the issue appears to each language pairs.

I didn't find any information about the cold start or readiness probes in the documentation.

The question is: Is it possible to somehow avoid a cold start?

Comment: Could you please specify the time  you left the model  without use?  And  how you are calling the model  REST API, Python code, both?  I made some test  by my own, and I was not able to reproduce the issue,  is supposed that once the model is deployed it is available to use it without any re-deploy  or cold start.

Comment: @EnriqueZetina I updated my question. It's weird because I face the same issue when I try it on the GCP.